# Import python modules given direct path

Tags: python

I have a module with `__init__.py` located in a specific path. Then I:

```
import sys    
sys.path.append('C:/Users/ME/Dropbox/Python/Library/ModuleDir')
```

But when I `from ModuleDir.x import classA`, it doesn't recognize the statement meaning that it wasn't able to find the module. What am I missing?

Under `ModuleDir`:

```
ModuleDir
    __init__.py
    X.py
    Subdir
        __init__.py
        y.py
```

Comment: Could you post the full traceback?

Comment: theres no error, it just doesn't recognize the module at all. theres a red line whenever i tried to import

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the directory *containing* the package subdir to your path:

```
sys.path.append('C:/Users/ME/Dropbox/Python/Library')
```

See [docs.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Answer (score 0):

Try [sys.path.insert()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)

```
import sys 
sys.path.insert(1, 'C:/Users/ME/Dropbox/Python/Library/')
from ModuleDir.x import classA
```

Comment: nope that didn't work. do i need to add something? i mean i added init.py file into ModuleDir already